# Java multi thread communication

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm relatively new using **Java multi-threading and concurrence tools**. I'm implementing an app which has an event producer (let's call it `EventProducer`). `EventProducer` has a thread pool `FixedThreadPool`, where one new thread per event to process is sent, submiting a new `EventProcessor` thread to the pool.

That's going all right, a thread in the pool is being created per event arrived. But problem is that I want to communicate that `EventProcessor` thread (which is specific for each event request) with two threads that are supposed to be application scoped, I mean, I'll have only an instance of them in the application, let's say `Service1` and `Service2`. Both of them have thread pools, to be able to process the tasks concurrently.

That specific `EventProcessor` sends sets of tasks to `Service1` and it returns responses for each task. For that responses, I have looked for [CompletionService](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/09/java-concurrency-part-7-executors-and-thread-pools/) but I don't know how can I integrate it with [Blocking queues](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) for bi-directional communication.  After, depending on that response, `EventProcessor` sends one action or another to execute in `Service2`. `Service2` will also send a response about that action to `EventProcessor`.

Anybody knows about how can I tackle such problem? I need an introduction in order to achieve the first steps. Pool your ideas.

Comment: @ jtahlborn, your comment is not really adding any values to his/her problem !

Comment: @jtahlborn I've been looking examples about that for hours, I tried making my problem specific enough to write here.

Comment: @user717630 Actually, it is. The OP wants to create new threads for each event. His threads Service1 and Service2 have thread pools. So maybe he is confusing some terms here.

Comment: What does the `EventProcessor` thread do while it's waiting for `Service1` etc. to finish? I ask because if you want two way communication you need to know when your submitted task is done.

Comment: Actually I have it implemented in other way, but I suppose it has to be waitting for them. Is it a dessing issue?

Comment: For how to use a CompletionService, look here: http://markusjais.com/understanding-java-util-concurrent-completionservice/

Comment: If it's waiting for the response on you can just use `Future` and the `Future.get()` method, if you want to carry on processing then this becomes more tricky...

Comment: @user717630 - the question isn't really clear enough to provide much in the way of meaningful help.  seems like the OP needs more basics on concurrency (as stated in the first and last sentences of the question) before diving in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I managed to solve it in the following way: `EventProducer` creates services `Service1` and `Service2`, which are runnable objects, and launches them as threads. Each of these service keeps waitting for result on its pool, which is implemented as `CompletionService`. Those service reference is keeped in `EventProducer` and passed by reference to every `EventProcessor`, which is created when an event is launched.

`EventProcessor` has two `BlockingQueue` elements, each of them is used to receive responses from the services. When I want to call a service, I do it trough the object's reference and call the dispatch method of the service, passing a collection of elements I want to process as parameter and also the reference of `EventProcessor` itself. The call is done following the thread of `EventProcessor`, but it only creates a callable object per object to process, executing code into the service class, which submits the new threads to his pool.

When the result is given, the service, which is waiting for it in his own thread, puts it into the `BlockingQueue` of the `EventProcessor`, because it has his reference. After `EventProcessor` manages the results into his own thread (and can send other actions to other services).

That's all, many thanks for people helping, you've your upvotes because every answer has clarified me some concept.

Answer (score 3):

The best object for inter-thread communications is the `BlockingQueue`. They are super-flexible and thread safe and will usually handle all requirements.

```
BlockingQueue<Task> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Let you Service1 and 2 be `ExecutorService`s. Your EventProcessor sends tasks in the form of Callables to Service1, using a return type R that encapsulates your response. It also queues up the resulting Futures. In another thread, you receive those responses and dispatch new callables to Service2. You can also use a CompletionService for that.

Comment: So your proposal is creating another thread which dispatches new requests to `Service2`? You think it's my best not to use `EventProcessor` for doing that work?

Comment: You seem to have a processing pipeline, where jobs come from nowhere to your EventProcessor, then to Service1 then maybe to Service2. This *maybe* should be handled by another thread. You could also wrap your Service1-jobs into Runnables that create new events for your Eventprocessor and put them into the same queue as your original jobs. But then you must decide what is for Service1 and what for Service2.

Answer (score 1):

What if you have a non-blocking queue in your event dispatcher thread, such as the [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html). You then pass a reference to that into your `Callable` so it can add responses to the queue.
In your event dispatcher you could then periodically poll the queue to see if it has anything interesting in it. As the queue is non blocking it would just return `null` when it's empty.